# Management Questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question(s) that I want to post about Management. However, it is about 2 employees, with similar problems, roles, and backgrounds (thus sources of issues) but drastically different personalities. Should I post it as two questions or one?

---

As suggested the below I was about to write a draft...but as I delved further into it I realized that it really is two questions. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If it would require two different answers, then pose it as two questions. If not, one.

Comment: You can edit into this post your current draft/idea of your question, so we can take a better look at it and suggest if it should be one or two posts

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure about a question, run it past us here, or in chat.  You can get a good deal of valuable feedback.

Either edit this post, or create another and include some basic information about the problem.